# How to use pointer to member inside a class object (right syntax)?

Tags: c++

In this example i'm trying to return `x`, `y` or `z` from `get_by_ptr` function, but can't unedrastand rigth(legal) syntax to do it. I understand that `this` pointer holds base address of object and `pointer to member` holds "address shift" and I can calculate address. But is there legal syntax way?

```
class foo {
public:
    size_t x{ 33 };
    size_t y{ 77 };
    size_t z{ 99 };
    size_t get_by_ptr(size_t foo::*ptr) {
        //how to return x, y or z using ptr
    }
};

int main() {
    foo bar;
    size_t foo::*ptr{ &foo::y };
    size_t z{ bar.get_by_ptr(ptr) };
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want to write:

```
size_t get_by_ptr(size_t foo::*ptr) {
    return this->*ptr;
}
```

Comment: @OomphSonar No, I don't think so - you've asked a perfectly valid question that's also a bit difficult to google. That the answer is simple is not your fault, it's the language's feature :).